# How to delete only some sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is what I am doing (I copied and tried to adapt it from old messages) :

1) inside a spreadsheet that have many sheets create a sheet and renamed it "TOC"

2) in "TOC", add this formula inside A1: =SheetNames( GoogleClock() )

3) Once copied in Google Apps Script, run function "SheetNames" below

```
function SheetNames() { // this will create a list of all the sheets ;)
try {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()
  var out = new Array( sheets.length+1 ) ;
  out[0] = [ "Name" , "gid" ];
  for (var i = 1 ; i < sheets.length+1 ; i++ ) out[i] = [sheets[i-1].getName() , sheets[i-1].getSheetId() ];
  return out
}
catch( err ) {
  return "#ERROR!" 
}
}
```

4) run function "delete_only_some_sheets"

```
function delete_only_some_sheets() {
// CAUTION !! It will delete some sheets ! 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var source = ss.getSheetByName("TOC");
for (var i = 3; i<=5; i++){ // !!! HERE adapt the "5" number to your needs here
var tet = source.getRange(["B"]+[(i)]).getValues();

//ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetId()[tet]); ///ERROR here ! ;(
   ss.deleteActiveSheet();
   //ss.deleteSheetId()[tet]; //possible ??

}
}
```

I keep getting the error "Cannot find method "setActiveSheet(."" And I am blocked. ;(

Many thanks in advance ;)

**EDIT :**

Hello,
Thanks to "Srik", I have found the solution ! ;)
Part 1) to 3) are the same. Part 4) becomes :

4) run function "delete_only_some_sheets"

```
function delete_only_some_sheets() {
// CAUTION !! IT will delete some sheets ! 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var source = ss.getSheetByName("TOC");
for (var i = 3; i<=5; i++){ // !!! HERE adapt the "5" number to your needs here
var tet = source.getRange(["A"]+[(i)]).getValues();

ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(tet));
ss.deleteActiveSheet();

}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, there is no `getSheetId()` method. I assume you are referring to the `getSheets()` method here which returns an array of `Sheet` objects.

Second, `setActiveSheet()` takes a `Sheet` object as an argument. Using `getSheets()` method, you can simply do it as follows

```
ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[i]);
```

There is no need to read the TOC sheet, fetch the id etc.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your help.;) I have a problem with the second part : over the time I have deleted by hand some sheets in my spreadsheet...so I am not deleting sheet(3) +sheet(4)+sheet(5). In fact I am deleting sheet(76)+sheet(112)+sheet(34) and it will be other numbers for other spreadsheets, hence the idea to list the sheet names and their id in the sheet "TOC" ! Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Hi again, Thank to you. I have found the solution. see above. Thank you very much. ;)

Comment: Cool. Since you new here, I'd like to remind that if you are happy with the answer, you should  accept it by clicking the tick mark next to the answer.